# Does combination needed to be considered in fixed sequence?

Tags: probability

Question: 
What is the probability of these events when we randomly select a permutation of the 26 lowercase letters of the English alphabet?
i. The first 13 letters of the permutation are in alphabetical order.

My efforts:I searched through the web and found 2 solutions:
i) = 1*13!/26!
ii) = 26C13*13!/26!

My confusion is, which one is correct? I doubt over (i) because of the absence of 26C13, but the web says since there's only 1 unique way of such combination so it only needs to *1, but not 26C13. I screwed up -_-

Comment: When in doubt, it is good to consider boundary cases; ex apply your solutions to the case of "first 26 letters" instead of "first 13 letters"

Comment: "26C13*13!/26!" is a rather peculiar way to write $1/13!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ii) is the correct one. There are $\binom{26}{13}$ ways to select $13$ letters out of $26$ and there is a unique way to arrange them in alphabetical order. Then there are $13!$ ways to place the remaining letters. Hence the required probability is
$$\frac{\binom{26}{13}\cdot 13!}{26!}=\frac{1}{13!}.$$